# How to only get Trello notifications when tagged?

Tags: trello

If I am tagging someone in my team, I want that person to instantly get an email notification.

Other events in Trello are not worth sending notification emails about.

Is this possible? Or scheduled as a possibility in the near future?

Answer (score 1):

With Trello free and Trello gold, notifications are controlled by individual users. Click your name, go to settings, then scroll to the Notifications area. You have 3 settings here: never, periodically, and instantly.

As long as notifications are set to periodically or instantly, you will always receive notifications when you are tagged/mentioned in a card.

I don't believe there is a way for an admin to force notification frequency in the bottom tiers of Trello, not without a 3rd party integration (such as pinging a Slack user or channel when mentioned).

More information here: http://help.trello.com/article/793-receiving-trello-notifications

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will also get notified upon events that I pay no interest for. In other words, the question remains.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now. You're asking for is a way to have a finer grained control over the types of activities that trigger a notification, yes? Trello Business Class might have better controls for notifications (I'm not a Business class user so I can't speak for that) if the current subscribe and assign options are not meeting your specific needs. Otherwise, I'll look out for a third-party solution. Sorry for the misunderstanding!